# Casting into the Date format Issue In TPT Script

Tags: teradata

I am working on a TPT script where I am getting input a flat file in below format.

```
File.txt

12191|2010-04-06|2010-09-08
28036|2009-05-20|2009-05-20
30742|2016-05-27|2016-05-27
```

Below is the portion of code from TPT scripts. I am not able to run this script as it is failing during computation of casting into the date format.

```
APPLY
( 
'INSERT INTO '||@WorkingDatabase||'.'||@TargetTable||'(
id
,actvtn_dt
,end_dt
,load_dt_tm
) VALUES
(
:id
, CAST(:actvtn_dt AS DATE FORMAT ''YYYY-MM-DD'')
, CAST(:end_dt AS DATE FORMAT ''YYYY-MM-DD'')
, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)
);'
)
```

Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: It looks Ok at first blush. What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: please add the ddl for the table.  Is there a format defined on the target load_dt_tm?

Comment: Why do you want to cast it, it's the default date format anyway?

Comment: @dnoeth - I understand, I ran the code without casting also as the date format is same but, it is putting all the records into the error table. That's why I am trying to cast it manually.

Comment: @ULick - The date format is same "YYYY-MM-DD" at table level. This is something unexpected to me.

Comment: Thank you guys for having look on this issue. It got resolved. It was due to the space in the date field. I have added trim function & it worked fine for me.